# python for each match in a string copy to an array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm doing some queries against a database that's going to return something like the following -

```
string = 'T=1 ID=56494759 DID=583887 O=N M=N J=76732 R=0 P=1 S=101 WR=N T=1 ID=56494760 DID=418400 O=N M=N J=48064 R=14780471 P=1 S=101 WR=N T=1 ID=56494761 DID=583889 O=N M=N J=76733 R=0 P=1 S=101 WR=N '
```

What I want to be able to do is wherever it says `ID=` I want that integer after it. and append them into an array like so -

```
array = [56494759, 56494760, 56494761]
```

From there I understand how to do the rest I need to do (use each value in the array to run a separate query against the DB).

Comment: [Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) can be helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethign like this:

```
string = 'T=1 ID=56494759 DID=583887 O=N M=N J=76732 R=0 P=1 S=101 WR=N T=1 ID=56494760 DID=418400 O=N M=N J=48064 R=14780471 P=1 S=101 WR=N T=1 ID=56494761 DID=583889 O=N M=N J=76733 R=0 P=1 S=101 WR=N '


import re

print(re.findall(r'\sID=(\d+)', string))
```

Results in:

```
['56494759', '56494760', '56494761']
```

Comment: Is there any way to NOT get the DID in that?  Maybe preface the r' ID='?

Comment: thanks!  Actually weirdness too seems the DB has a hidden character before the ID so I actually had to do this - r'xID=(\d+)'
the x is an SOH character.  hidden to unicode but to the program it uses it as a character break of sorts.

Comment: @whoisearth no worries. So i guess, you got it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
myString = 'T=1 ID=56494759 DID=583887 O=N M=N J=76732 R=0 P=1 S=101 WR=N T=1 ID=56494760 DID=418400 O=N M=N J=48064 R=14780471 P=1 S=101 WR=N T=1 ID=56494761 DID=583889 O=N M=N J=76733 R=0 P=1 S=101 WR=N '
array = [each.split('=')[1] for each in myString.split() if each.startswith('ID=')]
print array
```

Result :

```
['56494759', '56494760', '56494761']
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner that uses `map`...

```
filter(None, map(lambda x: None if x[0]!='ID' else x[1], map(lambda y: y.split('='), string.split())))
```

Or using `reduce` which may be a bit clearer:

```
reduce(lambda ids, x: ids + [x[1]] if x[0]=='ID' else ids, map(lambda x: x.split('='), string.split(' ')), [])
```